# Drop down Menu Flickering ghost error

Tags: css, wordpress

I have spent over 7 hours now in 2 sessions :( so I need help badly.
I have a simple css based menu, it has dropdown menus, when I rollover the dropdown menus there is an annoying flickering over the menus, its probably the mouse pointer not hiding properly or I dont know what is causing this.. I have integrated it with wordpress, please take a look here..

http://goo.gl/h6tyoy

Rollover the menu "Drop Down" and quickly move the mouse up and down and you will notice this flickering..

```
 /*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
 .sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu li {
  position: relative;
}
.sf-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.sf-menu > li {
  float: left;
}
.sf-menu li:hover > ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.sf-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.sf-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

/* Skin part */

.sf-menu a {
  color:#FFFFFF;            
  font-size:12px !important;
  font-family:Open Sans;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-transform:normal;
  padding: 3px 13px 3px 13px ;
}
.sf-menu li {
  background: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap; /* no need for Supersubs plugin */   
}          
.sf-menu li:hover,
.sf-menu li.sfHover {
  background: #5e418d;
  color:red;
}          
.sf-menu li.selected,
.sf-menu li.current-cat,
.sf-menu li.current-cat-parent,
.sf-menu li.current_page_item,
.sf-menu li.current_page_parent,
.sf-menu li.current_page_ancestor {
  background: #5e418d;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sf-menu li.current-menu-item a,
.sf-menu li.current-menu-item a:hover,
.sf-menu li.current-page-ancestor a,
.sf-menu li.current-page-ancestor a:hover,
.sf-menu li.current-menu-ancestor a,
.sf-menu li.current-menu-ancestor a:hover,
.sf-menu li.current-menu-parent a,
.sf-menu li.current-menu-parent a:hover,
.sf-menu li.current_page_parent a,
.sf-menu li.current_page_parent a:hover,
.sf-menu li.current_page_ancestor a,
.sf-menu li.current_page_ancestor a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.sf-menu li:hover > a, .sf-menu li.sfhover > a { color:#FFFFFF; }  

.sf-menu .sub-menu a { 

  color:#ffffff !important;            
  font-size:12px !important;
  font-family:Open Sans;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-transform:normal;
  padding: 3px 13px 3px 13px ;
}
.sf-menu .sub-menu a:hover { color:#444444 !important; }

.sf-menu ul li {
  background: #020202; /*sub-menu background */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}          
.sf-menu ul li:hover,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    border-top: 2px solid #5e418d;
 }           
.sf-menu .sub-menu li:last-child{ 
  -webkit-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px; 
     -moz-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px; 
          border-radius:0 0 3px 3px; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the problem. It's working fine.

Comment: I am using Mozilla.. if its browser specific ?

Comment: I just recorded a video with camstudio.. in video it looks fine, it means it has something to do with my monitor obviously... I will check on another monitor and report back.. till then no need to waste time as I have doubt with the screen resolution and monitor itself.. thanks

Comment: Yes, because I see no problem in firefox also. But if you do find a way to recreate it, let me know.